# How do I remove the restart etc. options on server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008

On Server 2008's Start menu I can select "Log Off", "Lock", "Restart", and "Shut Down"

I wish to remove the "Restart" and "Shut Down" options for all users so that they can't accidentally click on this and are forced to use the manual command options. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit your group policy settings to remove these options:

GPEDIT.MSC -> User Configuration -> Admin templates -> Start menu and taskbar.

Find:
`Remove and prevent access to the Shut Down, Restart, Sleep, and Hibernate commands`

And set to enable.

Comment: How is this done in Windows Server 2008 Standard SP1 (not 2008 R2)? The commands appear as buttons on the Start Menu as opposed to menu options

Answer (score 2):

There is a local security policy or GPO setting that allows you to remove the commands and only allow "log off".  We use it on some servers.

See these links:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617162%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

http://www.techpavan.com/2008/08/08/how-to-disable-enable-shutdown-logoff-start-menu/